# XSL transform failing when ampersand in XML string

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

When I try to transform XML containing & (ambersand) , below error is coming , how to escape it.

**Error :**

> Unable to generate the XML document using the provided XML/XSL input.
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 61; The
> reference to entity "LOB" must end with the ';' delimiter. You most
> likely forgot to escape '&' into '&'

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<store> <!-- Root Element -->
    <book id ="5350192956">
        <bookname>https://test.com/logon.jsp?fromLoc=ALL&LOB=COLLogon</bookname> 
        <authorname>Michael Kay</authorname>
        <publisher>Wrox</publisher>
        <price>$40</price> 
        <edition>4th</edition>         
    </book> 
    <book id ="3741122298">
        <bookname>Head First Java</bookname> 
        <authorname>Kathy Sierra</authorname>
        <publisher>O'reilly</publisher>
        <price>$19</price> 
        <edition>1st</edition>         
    </book>
    <book id ="9987436700">
        <bookname>SQL The Complete Reference</bookname> 
        <authorname>James R. Groff</authorname>
        <publisher>McGraw-Hill</publisher>
        <price>$45</price> 
        <edition>3rd</edition>         
    </book>
</store>
```

**XSL :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0"  >          
        <xsl:template match = "/">           
            <html>   
                <body>  
                    <h2>Books:-</h2>   
                    <table border = "1">   
                        <tr bgcolor = "#cd8932">   
                            <th>Book ID</th>   
                            <th>Book Name</th>   
                            <th>Author Name</th>   
                            <th>Publisher</th>   
                            <th>Price</th>                           
                            <th>Edition</th>
                        </tr>                        
                        <xsl:for-each select="store/book">   
                            <tr bgcolor = "#84cd32">   
                                <td><xsl:value-of select = "@id"/></td>   
                                <td><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select = "bookname" /></td>   
                                <td><xsl:value-of select = "authorname"/></td>   
                                <td><xsl:value-of select = "publisher"/></td>   
                                <td><xsl:value-of select = "price"/></td>                               
                                <td><xsl:value-of select = "edition"/></td>
                            </tr>   
                        </xsl:for-each>   
                    </table>   
                </body>   
            </html>   
        </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You need to understand that XSLT can only transform well-formed XML. If the XML is broken, as this is, you need to work out why it's broken and fix the program or process that allowed broken XML to be created in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This XML element contains an unescaped `&` character:

```xml
<bookname>https://test.com/logon.jsp?fromLoc=ALL&LOB=COLLogon</bookname>
```

It should be encoded like this:

```xml
<bookname>https://test.com/logon.jsp?fromLoc=ALL&amp;LOB=COLLogon</bookname>
```

Comment: how can I encode in XSL ?

Comment: @theRoot Your XML is invalid, you must fix it. You can't do it at the XSL level.

Answer (score 1):

There's no Almost-XML standard so XML tools are out. Which is why the
input file should be rejected.

But if deadlines are tight you could do worse than try [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint)
(which strips the XML declaration here):

```sh
xmllint --recover --html  --xmlout --dropdtd --xpath 'html/body/*' file.xml  2>/dev/null |
diff --ignore-all-space --context=1 file.xml -
```

- `--recover` output any parsable portions
- `--html` use the HTML parser
- `--xpath '…'` strips the HTML wrapper
- `2>/dev/null` discards errors from the HTML parsing